task scheduler library does not synch properly wit AD
I have Windows Server 2022 Datacenter 21H2 and a Windows 11 Pro 23H2 machine
I created 2 gpo-s with some scheduled tasks.
I deleted one of the tasks from windows server GPO manager but after many gpoupdate /force on the windows 11 machine task still continue to stay in the task scheduler library of windows machine.
So how can i make windows server to ( i do not know the right word ) check what gpo-s have to put on windows machines and if windows machine have scheduled task that is not existing in server gpo to delete it from the windows machine

In the group policy Scheduled Task's properties window, on the Common tab, there is an option to Remove this item when it is no longer applied. It is not enabled by default:

Note: to remove existing scheduled tasks without applying new ones, just create a task object with a matching Name and set the Action to Delete:


The option you are talking about is enabled.
Strange thing is that the task was deleted from group policy managment but still existing in the windows 11 machine ...

@PhilipScot How can the option be enabled if the task was deleted? Also, if the option was enabled after the task was removed or stopped applying, then the PC will not know to remove the task. A less-common issue is that the option does not work with roaming user profiles (if the task is a User policy). If it was set properly, there should be an entry for that gpo in the policy history folder for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/remove-this-item-if-it-is-no-longer-applied-option#more-information
